# backbone.js IE support

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js

Which IE browser versions officially supported by backbone.js?

backbonejs.org quote:

`Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( >= 1.8.3). For RESTful persistence and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include jQuery ( >= 1.11.0), and json2.js for older Internet Explorer support. (Mimics of the Underscore and jQuery APIs, such as Lodash and Zepto, will also tend to work, with varying degrees of compatibility.)`

But i need more detailed answer, does IE8 supported?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How cross browser is backbone.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389222/how-cross-browser-is-backbone-js)

Comment: My interest mostly focused on IE browser support, especially old versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery browser support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) starts at IE9 but version 1.12 is still recommended for older browser and Backbone is compatible with [jQuery 1.12](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/#jquery-all-1.x).

You can test [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/test/) and [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/test/) with their extensive unit tests on the target browsers.

See [How cross browser is backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389222/how-cross-browser-is-backbone-js) for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

backbone still supports IE8. We have a web application developed using backbone / underscore and never noticed compatibility issue in IE8 browsers. Just make sure that you keep using jquery 1.12, because that's the only version that supports older browser.

Sebastian